# Limiting /proc/cpuinfo output to a single CPU/core

Tags: files

CPU cores in Linux, `/proc/cpuinfo`, are separated with an empty line. How would you go about printing the information only for the first core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take:

```bsh
awk '{if ($0=="") exit; print $0}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

Comment: worked fine in a jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

If the point of the exercise is code golfing, here goes:

```
awk '!$0{exit}1' /proc/cpuinfo
```

or

```
sed -n '/^$/q;p' /proc/cpuinfo
```

(`sed '/^$/q' /proc/cpuinfo` is shorter but prints the concluding blank line).

Comment: Nice, thanks..!

Comment: AWK can be surprisingly concise, especially with the `1` trick ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What about `sed -n '1,/^$/p' /proc/cpuinfo` ? And don't forget a bit newer way `lscpu`.